# How to prevent my additions to authorized keys from being overwritten by puppet?

Tags: centos, ssh, puppet, authorization

At my company all employees are given a private key, which get's renewed each year, that they should use to connect to VMs.  The SA here have a puppet script which will look up my public key and save it into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on any VM so I can connect to it.

The problem is that they are overwriting the authorized_keys file.  That means any other keys I add to the file are also overwritten.  This frustrates me since I like to be able to connect from box A to box B, mostly so I can SCP, and I don't want to put my personal private key on box A since it's a box multuple users have sudo permissions on.  I'd usually create a new ssh key per box and add that boxes public key to the other boxes authorized_users, but this keeps being erased by puppet.

Is there any means I can keep additional authorized keys from being overwritten without changing the puppet scripts themselves, which I don't maintain?

Failing that is there an easy way that the puppet scripts could be modified to not overwrite my additions, but still allow them to update my public key, that I could suggest to the SA's?

The VM's are centos machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any means I can keep additional authorized keys from being overwritten without changing the puppet scripts themselves, which I don't maintain?

If you have administrative access on the server, you can configure `sshd` to look in multiple locations for your authorized keys. From `sshd_config(5)`:

> ```
> AuthorizedKeysFile
>
> Specifies the file that contains the public keys used for user authentication.
> The format is described in the AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT
> section of sshd(8).  Arguments to AuthorizedKeysFile accept the tokens
> described in the TOKENS section.  After expansion, AuthorizedKeysFile
> is taken to be an absolute path or one relative to the user's home
> directory.  Multiple files may be listed, separated by whitespace.
> Alternately this option may be set to none to skip checking for user
> keys in files.  The default is ".ssh/authorized_keys
> .ssh/authorized_keys2".
> ```

---

> Failing that is there an easy way that the puppet scripts could be modified to not overwrite my additions, but still allow them to update my public key, that I could suggest to the SA's?

That should also be easy. The [ssh_authorized_key](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/types/ssh_authorized_key.html) resource has a `purge_ssh_keys` flag (off by default) that controls whether or not it cleans out unmanaged keys from your `authorized_keys` file.